# mysql trigger is not working for stipulated query why

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS expt13;
CREATE DATABASE expt13;
USE expt13;
CREATE TABLE student(tid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30), sub_1 int2, sub_2 int2, sub_3 int2, total int3, percentage int3);
DESC student;
INSERT INTO student (tid,name,sub_1,sub_2,sub_3) values
(1,"priya",23,45,56),
(2,"shree",45,56,67),
(3,"mala",45,32,65);
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER stud_marks before insert ON student
for each row 
begin
update student set student.total=student.sub_1+student.sub_2+student.sub_3 where(student.total is null);
update student set student.percentage=student.total*60/100 where(student.percentage is null);
 end//
 DELIMITER ;
 SELECT * FROM student;
```

the trigger was created successfully but not working in the query

[image: output]

sql and I expect the output with triggers

Comment: You cannot effect the table on which the trigger is defined on. You must alter a value in NEW pseudocolumn with according SET statement.

Comment: I do not see the reason for to calculate the values for the columns when these values are calculated from another row values. Use generated column instead, and you do not need in triggers.

Comment: *but not working in the query* An insertion attempt must fail with error message `Can't update table 'student' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Answer (score 0):

Use generated column.

```
CREATE TABLE student(
  tid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  sub_1 int2,
  sub_2 int2, 
  sub_3 int2,
  total int3 AS (sub_1+sub_2+sub_3),
  percentage int3 AS ((sub_1+sub_2+sub_3)*60/100));
INSERT INTO student (tid,name,sub_1,sub_2,sub_3) values
(1,"priya",23,45,56),
(2,"shree",45,56,67),
(3,"mala",45,32,65);
SELECT * FROM student;
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| tid | name | sub_1 | sub_2 | sub_3 | total | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | priya | 23 | 45 | 56 | 124 | 74 |
| 2 | shree | 45 | 56 | 67 | 168 | 101 |
| 3 | mala | 45 | 32 | 65 | 142 | 85 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L9qC_Zv-)

PS. `percentage` formula seems to be strange..